# CSS does not link to the HTML page

Tags: html, css

I tried adding media, rel but it did not work.CSS file is in the same directory as html files. My other website's css work but unfortunately this does not. I am trying to link externally(with link tag). I looked to similar issues but none solved my problem. Thank you for your help.

**My files:**

```css
body {
  background - color: #ffffff;
  text - decoration - color: #003366;
  font-family: Arial;
}

head {
  background-color: # 003366;
  text - decoration - color: #AEC3E3;
  font - family: "Times New Roman";
}

h1 {
  line - height: 200 %;
  text - indent: 1e m;
}

nav {
  font - weight: bold;
}

dt {
  text - decoration - color: #5280C5;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
}

.category {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration-color: # 5380 C5;
  font - family: "Times New Roman";
}

footer {
  font - size: .70e m;
  font - style: italic;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fishcreek.css" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Fish Creek Animal Clinic</title>
  <h1>Fish Creek Animal Clinic</h1>
</head>

<body>

  <nav><a href="home.html">Home</a> <a href="menu.html">Menu</a> <a href="music.html">Music
    
            </a><a href="jobs.html">Jobs </a>

  </nav>
  <dl>
    <dt>Full Service Facility</dt>
    <dd>Doctors and staff are on duty 24 hours a day, 7 days a week.</dd>

    <dt>Years of Experience</dt>
    <dd>Fish Creek Veterinarians have provided quality, dependable care for your beloved <br> animals since 1984. </dd>

    <dt> Open Door Policy </dt>
    <dd>Our professionals welcome owners to stay with their pets during any <br> medical procedure. </dd>



  </dl>


  <p>888-555-5555<br> 1242 Grassy Lane<br> Fish Creek, WI 55534



  </p>
  <footer>Copyright &copy; 2018 Fish Creek Animal Clinic <br>
    <a href="memohacan@gmail.com">memohacan@gmail.com</a>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>

</html>
```

Comment: Is the css filename "fishcreek.css" and is this css file in the same folder as "index.html" ? Note that the line `<h1>Fish Creek Animal Clinic</h1>` must be between `<body>` and `</body>`

Comment: yes sorry for misleading header. css file name : fishcreek.css. And yes it is in the same folder as index.html.

Comment: The `text-decoration-color` property is only supported in the **latest** browser versions. It is **not** supported in Edge and (without prefix) not in Safari. Using this property may cause unexpected results. Specifying a `type="text/css"`  is not required because you have declared a `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Fish Creek Animal Clinic</title>
    <h1>Fish Creek Animal Clinic</h1>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fishcreek.css" />
    </head>

    <body>

    <nav><a href="home.html">Home</a> <a href="menu.html">Menu</a> <a 
    href="music.html">Music

    </a><a href="jobs.html">Jobs </a>

    </nav>
    <dl>
      <dt>Full Service Facility</dt>
      <dd>Doctors and staff are on duty 24 hours a day, 7 days a week.</dd>

   <dt>Years of Experience</dt>
       <dd>Fish Creek Veterinarians have provided quality, dependable care for your beloved     <br> animals since 1984. </dd>

<dt> Open Door Policy </dt>
<dd>Our professionals welcome owners to stay with their pets during any <br> medical procedure. </dd>



   </dl>


  <p>888-555-5555<br> 1242 Grassy Lane<br> Fish Creek, WI 55534
```

Comment: Code only answers can generally be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work. Point out what you changed and why you think it will solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try to specify the file type by using the ''type" attribute, like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fishcreek.css" />
```

I have had the same issues before because I haven't specified the file type.

I have also noticed that there is a second closing HTML tag at the end of index.html.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `text-decoration-color` lines to avoid problems on some browsers. In the html below, the css file "fishcreek.css" is linked with the html. For testing I added a `color: green` to the body ;)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Fish Creek Animal Clinic</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fishcreek.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Fish Creek Animal Clinic</h1>
    <nav>
        <a href="home.html">Home</a>
        <a href="menu.html">Menu</a>
        <a href="music.html">Music</a>
        <a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a>
    </nav>
    <dl>
        <dt>Full Service Facility</dt>
        <dd>Doctors and staff are on duty 24 hours a day, 7 days a week.</dd>
        <dt>Years of Experience</dt>
        <dd>Fish Creek Veterinarians have provided quality, dependable care for your beloved
        <br>animals since 1984.</dd>
        <dt>Open Door Policy</dt>
        <dd>Our professionals welcome owners to stay with their pets during any
        <br>medical procedure.</dd>
    </dl>
    <p>888-555-5555
    <br>1242 Grassy Lane
    <br>Fish Creek, WI 55534</p>
    <footer>
        Copyright &copy; 2018 Fish Creek Animal Clinic
        <br><a href="memohacan@gmail.com">memohacan@gmail.com</a>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

fishcreek.css

```
body {
    color: green;
    font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
header {
    background-color: #003366;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
h1 {
    line-height: 200%;
    text-indent: 1em;
}
nav a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
}
nav a:hover,
nav a:active {
    color: red;
}
dt {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
.category {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
footer {
    font-size: .70em;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: This answer works fine on all browsers. No problem with linking css to html.